# How to specify return type in handler

Tags: ios, ios8

```
-(bool)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField {

    UIAlertController * blert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"your alert" message:@"are you sure you want to clear" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction * defautact = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){}];

    UIAlertAction * defautact1 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){}];

    [blert addAction:defautact];
    [blert addAction: defautact1];
    [self presentViewController:blert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I’m trying to use the `-(bool)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField` in this I’m creating a alert and including two buttons `ok` and `cancel` so if I press the button `ok` then the return value for the `-(bool)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField` must be `YES`
so if I press the button `cancel` then the return value for the `-(bool)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField` must be `NO`

Can you please tell me how to do this in the handler

Comment: why you don't use the handler inside each UIAlertAction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the handler of each UIAlertControl to set a global NSString to Yes or No and then you can evaluate it after "self presentViewController". The handler is a block of instructions.

```
        UIAlertAction *YesAction = [UIAlertAction
                                       actionWithTitle:@"Yes"
                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                       {
                                           NSLog(@"Tap on Yes");

                                           //Here you can set a global variable (reply for example) or make any action
                                           reply = @"yes";
                                       }];
```

Comment: the block of code that is present in the handler is not getting executed

Comment: did you see the string by NSLog? No?

Comment: hello i just figured out what is the problem
but i am unable to fix it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32938532/ios-uialertcontroller-code-flow-control

this the new question 
and you can find the explanation of the problem

Comment: So the best way is manage all the code directly inside the handler blocks