# iOS UIAlertController code flow control

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

```
-(bool)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UIAlertController * blert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"your alert" message:@"are you sure you want to clear" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction * defautact = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
        NSLog(@"tao on YES");
        // click= YES;
        _baba =@"yes";
    }];

    UIAlertAction * defautact1 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
        NSLog(@"Press on YES");
        // click= NO;
        //field1.text=@"";
        _baba=@"no";
    }];

    [blert addAction:defautact];
    [blert addAction: defautact1];

    [self presentViewController:blert animated:YES completion:nil];

    if([_baba isEqualToString:@"yes"])
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When this method is called first the `if` block is executed and then the `UIAlertController` is getting executing so that i an getting an undetermined result so can any one solve this problem and make it work in a revere order.

Anyone can you tell me why the view controller is not triggering up last but not first?

Comment: `presentViewController` completes a synchronously - the function returns immediately (meaning that _baba won't be "yes") so your function returns false. When the user selects an option some time later, the block is executed. You need to return "false" from the function and then clear the text field directly in the block if required

Comment: thank you buddy it works great